# Facebook group member posts not going to group page

Tags: facebook-groups

I just created a Facebook group (closed) and all the members' posts are going to my inbox, instead of the group page. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Go to the group settings in the group page (Edit Group Settings)
- Check the bottom of the page where it says "Post Approval"
- Uncheck "All group posts must be approved by an admin" and see if it is still happening